# Laravel Vue.js component registration

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I am creating a simple Vue.js application with Laravel. I have registered Vue.js with:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';

Vue.use(VueRouter);

import App from './components/App';

    const app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        components: {
            App
        },
        router,
    });
```

If I create a custom component, this works just fine:

```
Vue.component('nav-section', {
    template: `<div>This is odd</div>`
});
```

I can then call `<nav-section></nav-section>` in any given template, and it will output "This is odd."

However if I use Laravel's require method like so:

```
Vue.component('nav-section', require('./components/Navigation'));
```

It is not working anymore. `<nav-section></nav-section>` is empty, blank.
No errors in npm or console. Am I missing something, or some logic behind require?

**Navigation.vue:**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <span>Sample text</span>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {}
</script>
```

**Vue.js:**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';

Vue.use(VueRouter);

import App from './components/App';

Vue.component('nav-section', require('./components/Navigation'));


    const app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        components: {
            App
        },
        router,
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try writing it out like this, with the extension and `default`:

```js
Vue.component('nav-section', require('./components/Navigation.vue').default);
```

Comment: Oh man, I did not even think to try it like this. Thank you indeed for this solution :-). So as long as default is attached .vue is "still" not necessary :-)

Comment: I expected it might, but I figured it wouldn't hurt to be thorough. :)